# Assigning Different IP addresses to Multiple Apps in Docker

Tags: linux, shell, docker, remote-access

I'm new to the concept of docker so this is just a conceptual question and not a programmatic question.I have understood quite a few distinguishing features about it by referring to the image displayed below..

[image: Docker]

What i want to know is that in docker can we assign different IPs to Different Apps & access them remotely using putty like in a Virtual Machine or all the Apps share a single IP address??

Comment: @usr1234567 apparently not - the distinguishing factor is whether the *asker* is a programmer. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276579/should-docker-questions-go-on-stackoverflow-or-serverfault-or-superuser

Comment: If I am a physicist trying docker should my question go to physics? The content of the of the question has some relevance to where it is on topic and high level architecture questions for very generic cases are probably not SO on-topic regardless of who asks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's exactly what docker does. Each app runs in an container within it's own network namespace. Docker assigns an ip address to each container automatically.

Use the following command to see the assigned ips:

```
docker inspect  -f "{{.Name}} {{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}}" $(docker ps -a -q)
```

You can start a ssh daemon inside the container and connect to it like to any other host.

The other (prefered) possibility is, to use the following command to get an "maintenance shell":

```
docker exec -ti mycontainer /bin/bash
```

This method follows the docker pattern "one app per container".

Comment: also `docker attach` if the app running in the container is interactive (like a shell)

Comment: yes of course. but i would not say a shell is the typical dockerized app. i use "docker attach" for playground and sandbox containers as well.

Answer (score 0):

As your containers are running on a host, from outside they will be accessible via that host IP. What will make the difference is the different ports you expose. More information in the Docker documentation: https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#binding-ports